# Opera Media Cache: find YouTube videos

Tags: linux, video, youtube, cache, opera

On Linux, Opera browser uses `~/.cache/opera/Media Cache` to cache media. I can find the recently modified media cache by running on terminal:

```
me@Linux-Machine:~/.cache/opera/Media Cache$ ls -lhrtci
```

which results:

```
//..a long list before this..//
889312 -rw------- 1 me me  593K Feb 18 15:43 67b5b4f930caf3d5_s
889307 -rw------- 1 me me  3.8K Feb 18 15:43 67b5b4f930caf3d5_0
889317 -rw------- 1 me me   11M Feb 24 05:19 5292814459c5a023_s
889310 -rw------- 1 me me  5.6K Feb 24 05:19 5292814459c5a023_0
885963 drwx------ 2 me me  4.0K Feb 24 06:14 index-dir
```

Based on size/date/name of the files, I assume `5292814459c5a023_s` and `5292814459c5a023_0` are related to one Youtube video I just watched. Probably one file is meta-data and the other is content.

But When I try to open either of them with GNOME MPlayer, I cannot. I wonder if anybody knows if this procedure is possible to retrieve Youtube videos from browser cache.

Comment: You hould try *youtube-dl* to download youtube videos, if getting this result is all you care for.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Just used `youtube-dl` with [this method](http://askubuntu.com/a/311445/407516) and observed how awesome it is.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Could you convert your comment into an answer so that I can accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/), if all you care about (like me!!) is the final result. Make sure to check which version of each video is available (with option *-F*), and you can then select it with *-f*.